# Can't get my GUI button to run on top of my stars

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I can't get my pygame GUI buttons to work on top of the star sheet I have created, Can anyone help me solve this.

**My Code**

```
import os,sys,random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()



def start_menu(screen):

    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 40)
    image = pygame.Surface((50,50))
    image.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.polygon(image,(255,255,255),[(200,200),(0,50),(25,25)],5)
    pos = 1
    option1 = font.render("BEGIN",True,(255,255,255))
    option2 = font.render("MY PROFILE",True,(255,255,255))
    option3 = font.render("INSTRUCTIONS",True,(255,255,255))
    option4 = font.render("QUIT",True,(255,255,255))

    N = 200
    SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H = (900, 600)
    pygame.init()

    pygame.display.set_caption('Starts Ja')

    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()


    stars = [
        [random.randint(0, SCREEN_W),random.randint(0, SCREEN_H)]
        for x in range(N)
    ]
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while 1:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                exit()
            elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == K_DOWN:
                    pos += 1
                    if pos > 4: pos = 1
                elif e.key == K_UP:
                    pos -= 1
                    if pos < 1: pos = 4
                elif e.key == K_RETURN:
                    if pos == 1:
                        import MathsvadersReal
                    elif pos == 4:
                        exit()
            clock.tick(22)
            screen.blit(option1,(100,100))
            screen.blit(option2,(200,200))
            screen.blit(option3,(200,300))
            screen.blit(option3,(200,400))
            screen.blit(image,(20,pos*100))
            background.fill((0,0,0))
            for star in stars:
                    pygame.draw.line(background,
                        (255, 255, 255), (star[0], star[1]), (star[0], star[1]))
                    star[0] = star[0] - 1
                    if star[0] < 0:
                        star[0] = SCREEN_W
                        star[1] = random.randint(0, SCREEN_H)
            screen.blit(background, (0,0))
            pygame.display.flip()



if __name__ == '__start_menu__': start_menu()
```

Comment: This doesn't run at all in the form you've posted here. 1. The indentation is screwed up. The indent after pygame.display.flip() is illegal. There's a mix of tabs and spaces there that makes it hard to tell what it's supposed to be. 2. `__name__` is never going to be `__start_menu__`, so the function won't be called. 3. The while loop will never terminate, so none of the code after it can run. Furthermore, you need to be more clear about what you expect it to do and what it actually does before anyone is likely to be able to help you.

Comment: I fixed the indent of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Your code was very wrong, as stated by [@Weeble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14843443/1931274).
I had changed a lot of things about your code including:

1. Made functions for displaying text and drawing stars, for readability.
2. There was no need of the background screen (removed); screen is enough.
3. Made code more readable by breaking into blocks by category.
4. Many changes for readability.

I had to spend a lot of time on this.

But,(still)
I have not put the code as a function, or the `if __name__ == ...` check.
You need to do something! Right? (if no, Quit Programming!)

Here's the reassembled version of your code, which turns out to be much more readable.

```py
import os,sys,random
import pygame
# NEVER use from ... import *, even if pygame docs tell you to do so.

def disp(phrase, loc, screen, color): # func to display text
    s = font.render(phrase, True, color)
    screen.blit(s, loc)

def draw_star(star): # drawing a star
    # you only need to change a pixel, so use set_at, not draw.line
    screen.set_at((star[0], star[1]), (255, 255, 255)) 
    star[0] -= 1
    if star[0] < 0:
        star[0] = screen.get_width()
        star[1] = random.randint(0, screen.get_height())

# Divide your code into parts on the basis of what it does like
# initialising pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Menu')
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 40)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# defining the image/marker
image = pygame.Surface((30,50))
image.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.draw.polygon(image,(255,255,255),[(0,0),(0,50),(25,25)],5)

# creating list of stars, used multi-line for loop for readability
stars = []
for i in range(200):
    x = random.randint(0, screen.get_width())
    y = random.randint(0, screen.get_height())
    stars.append([x,y])

pos = 1
while True:
    # events
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pos += 1
                if pos > 4:
                    pos = 1
            elif e.key == pygame.K_UP:
                pos -= 1
                if pos < 1:
                    pos = 4
            elif e.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                if pos == 1:
                    import MathsvadersReal
                elif pos == 4:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    # displaying text,image
    disp("Begin"       , (100,100), screen, (255, 255, 255))
    disp("My Profile"  , (100,200), screen, (255, 255, 255))
    disp("Instructions", (100,300), screen, (255, 255, 255))
    disp("Quit"        , (100,400), screen, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(image,(50, (pos * 100)-10 ))

    # drawing stars
    for star in stars:
        draw_star(star)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague and the code you have posted is quite messy.

I think your problem might well be that you are drawing your option text onto the screen, then completely covering it with your starfield.
You should move the option and cursor drawing down after `screen.blit(background, (0,0))`.
However, there are a fair number of other issues with the code as posted:

1. The indentation is all over the place. I suspect this is a copy and paste problem rather than an actual bug in your code, but it means that nobody can run it without first trying to figure out what you meant and fixing it up themselves.
2. `__name__` is never equal to `'__start_menu__'`. Is this code normally called from somewhere else? It's hard to know how to run it correctly.
3. `start_menu` takes one argument, but is called with none.
4. You call `pygame.init()`, but not `pygame.display.set_mode()`, so no window is created in this example. If you assume that the display has already been initialised and passed in, you shouldn't be initialising pygame again.
5. You draw option3 twice and don't draw option4.

Comment: yes, he is bliting the background onto screen after bliting all the buttons. Therefore, it covers everything up.